# jQuery change text on toggle

Tags: jquery

Below I'm trying to use jQuery to open and close a pane, but I'd also like to use jQuery to toggle the text too. Could someone assist in helping me rename `.chatstatus` to either `open` or `close` when its toggled?

```
    $('.chatstatus').click(function(){
        $('.mChatBodyFix').slideToggle(500);
        $.cookie('chatPane', $.cookie('chatPane')=='open'?"closed":"open", {expires:1});

        var chatstatustext = $('.chatstatus').text();
        $('.chatstatus').html() == chatstatustext?"close":"open";
    });
```

Comment: What sort of element is `chatstatus`? Are you sure you mean 'rename'?? The name of an input element in a form is used for sending the data back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
$('.chatstatus').html( chatstatustext == "open" ? "close" : "open" )
```

`html()` sets text of an element. So you can use a condition to set it to either 'open' or 'close' here.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your very last statement:

```
$('.chatstatus').html() == chatstatustext?"close":"open";
```

You are testing of `chatstatustext` is true or false, but it is a string value.  If `chatstatustext` contains any string other than an empty one it will always keep `.chatstatus` equal to "close".

Answer (score 0):

Set the text in the complete function of the `slideToggle()`, based on whether `mChatBodyFix` is visible or not:

```
$('.chatstatus').click(function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    $('.mChatBodyFix').stop().slideToggle(500, function() {
        $button.text( $(this).is(':visible') ? 'close' : 'open' );
    });

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kcvc/13/)